# Installing numpy - the system cannot find the file specified (msvcr90.dll)

Tags: python

I have been trying to get numpy to install for the last several hours now, and I'm finally giving up and asking for help.

First, I have tried:

I was first getting a "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" error, so I followed the recommendations from this question ([error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)) and installed Microsoft Visual V++ 2008 Express. This did absolutely nothing.

So then I tried using a different compiler altogether by installing mingw32 and making a disutils.cfg file with:

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32
```

And putting it in Python27\Lib\distutils

This got rid of the "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" error, but now I have the new error about msvcr90.dll.

I have no idea how to fix it, and I'm tired and just want numpy lol. Here is the entire output when I run python setup.py install:

```
\numpy-1.8.1>python setup.py install
Running from numpy source directory.
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
F2PY Version 2
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python
27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries  not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', '
C:\\Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\
Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Christie\Downloads\numpy-1.8.1\numpy-1.8.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.
py:1521: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs'
]
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Christie\Downloads\numpy-1.8.1\numpy-1.8.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.
py:1530: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Christie\Downloads\numpy-1.8.1\numpy-1.8.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.
py:1533: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python
27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Christie\Downloads\numpy-1.8.1\numpy-1.8.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.
py:1427: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\lib
s']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Christie\Downloads\numpy-1.8.1\numpy-1.8.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.
py:1438: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Christie\Downloads\numpy-1.8.1\numpy-1.8.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.
py:1441: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler opti
ons
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler opt
ions
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
building library "npymath" sources
'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Looking for python27.dll
Building msvcr library: "C:\Python27\libs\libmsvcr90.a" (from C:\Windows\winsxs\
amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_99b61f5e8371c1d4\msvc
r90.dll)
error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install using the binary executable directly rather than from the source. For you 32 bit http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html#windows or as you pointed out for the 64 bit version from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

[EDIT: Changed based on the comments and added link to 64 bit version]

Comment: I did, and unfortunately I had no success. Thank you for the suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to install it from source? could you try using the lightweight method mentioned [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html#windows)

Comment: They didn't have a link to the 64 bit version there; however, your suggestion worked. I got it from this site: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. If you edit your answer I'll accept it.