# pip install --user numpy , error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to install numpy in Pycharm with python2.7, I got this error :

```
error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified operable program or batch file.

'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Building msvcr library: "C:\Python27\libs\libmsvcr90.a" (from C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcr90.dll)

error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing numpy - the system cannot find the file specified (msvcr90.dll)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072357/installing-numpy-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-msvcr90-dll)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `gcc` (the compiler) on Windows and then add it to your `PATH` variable.

[Here is a link](http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/) on how to install it on Windows.

ETA: It might be easier to install the binaries which can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html).

Comment: I installed C:\cygwin64 , put C:\cygwin64\bin in the path, now it says :  error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory